# Passing & or &amp; via XML CData webrequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

When I do C# webrequest, I get 'Unterminated CDATA section' exception from response.

I pass & only in the CDATA. and found that this is the issue for the exception.
Any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check to close the CDATA section properly?

```
<![CDATA[
Your text
]]>
```